# AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtGui' has no attribute 'QApplication'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

ошибка выглядит так:

> AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtGui' has no attribute 'QApplication'

указывает на **4** строку. Помогите пржалуйста, ***Python 3.7.x***,  а ***PyQt 5.13.1***

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Первая программа на PyQt")
window.resize(300, 70)
label = QtGui.QLabel("<center>Привет, мир!</center>")
btnQuit = QtGui.QPushButton("&Закрыть окно")
vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(label)
vbox.addWidget(btnQuit)
window.setLayout(vbox)
QtCore.QObject.connect(btnQuit, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),QtGui.qApp, QtCore.SLOT("quit()"))

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не удачно взяли приложение написанное на `PyQt4`, поменяли `4` на `5`, но это немного не так.

В `PyQt5` добавлена модуль `QtWidgets` и виджеты разнесены. https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/#qt-modules

Привязка `сигналов и слотов` выполняется по новому стилю.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets     # + QtWidgets


#app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#window = QtGui.QWidget()
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

window.setWindowTitle("Первая программа на PyQt")
window.resize(300, 70)

label = QtWidgets.QLabel("<center>Привет, мир!</center>")
btnQuit = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Закрыть окно")
vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(label)
vbox.addWidget(btnQuit)
window.setLayout(vbox)

#QtCore.QObject.connect(btnQuit, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),QtWidgets.qApp, QtCore.SLOT("quit()"))
btnQuit.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)         # <---

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]